# Create MP4 or another playable video format from frame series of JPEG in a directory

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, jpeg

So I have frame series of JPEG in a folder let's say folder `cctv` where inside of that folder is only series of JPEG with unix timestamp named in nanosecond.

I mean like this ( I used tail because too much to display).

```
.../uwc/cctv $ ls | tail
1660282994647450349.jpg
1660282994732146495.jpg
1660282994809953109.jpg
1660282994883480141.jpg
1660282994965326703.jpg
1660282995051919515.jpg
1660282995128582224.jpg
1660282995203676963.jpg
1660282995296646495.jpg
1660282995373804099.jpg
```

I can display MJPEG from those series with OpenCV or Flask, but idk how to convert it to mp4.

I expect I can convert those series to mp4 with specifying frame rates I want for example 60 FPS. So how do I achieve it? I suspect `ffmpeg` can do it, but I never use so I don't know how to use it, maybe this will be my first time to use it.

Actually MJPEG is fine and playable in VLC but it will burden layman like entering URL stream of those JPEG or maybe need opening web browser.

And ofcourse I don't need audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one example command with `ffmpeg` how to create such video:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '166*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

This video is set to 30 FPS, H.264 codec. Feel free to change them if required.

For more info check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478183/2908599).

Comment: This works fine, but I have no idea what those parameters did, I only know `framerate`, `166*.jpg` means convert everything that has prefix `166` in jpg name. And another I dont know

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira, for the other options feel free to refer official `ffmpeg` documentation: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html